# Post migration from JDK 1.8 to JDK 11 facing compilation issues for SOAP Webservices for a Springboot Application

Tags: web-services, java-11

We did migration of existing Springboot application

JDK 1.8 to Open JDK 11

Jboss-eap 6.4 to   Jboss-eap 7.4

Entire Software application is qualified and tested but we are facing one issue for SOAP Webservice that is getting called from our application.

Problem :

WebService is configured as below in applicationContext.xml .  We are getting compile time exception as highlighted in JDK 11 setup as below

Application Context .xml :    [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cPth.png)

Issues for XSD :  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFJdR.png)

WebService Call  :  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD6Os.png)

Issue for Webservice : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KHh28.png)

Fix we did  :

In order to overcome the problem we changed the webservice namespace from `xmlns:wss` to `"xmlns:sws"` in applicationContext.xml

Application Context.xml :  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1NGxT.png)

WebService details in Application Context : [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNAxp.png)

Compile Time errors are removed but when we start the JBOSS we are getting below runtime exception JBOSS

Server Logs :  [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/842vO.png)

Please suggest how we can fix this issue or suggest any other way forward as the webservice execution was working fine on JDK1.8 and  and we are stuck for webservice calling over JDK11 setup.

Comment: Error in the server logs for reference :
11:20:49,478 ERROR [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 76) 
Context initialization failed: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: 
Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/web-services]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.